# Svg - Firefox calculating wrong width when setting stroke-width

Tags: html, css, dom, svg

Consider this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/5fdrjoo9/) in Chrome and FF:

---

in Chrome the `width` and `height` get calculated perfectly taking `stroke-width` in account.

In FF `width` and `height` properties have a little offset without stroke-width (in my ex. `4px`);
 but adding stroke-width has the following problems:

- will increase size of computed element adding stroke-width
- the element gets aligned to right making left part overflow

is this a known issue or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In path commands commas can only be placed between numbers if the markup is to be valid. The comma preceding the Z is invalid in your example and Firefox correctly rejects this, terminating the path at this point. Chrome incorrectly continues to parse the path.